# How do I execute other action than CRUD by ajax in Rails?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

So I'm new to Ajax in RoR and having first problem with executing **.js.erb** file after some action ends. By 'some action' I mean not default generated by Rails, because those seem to work fine.

Here's what I got:

- **index.html.erb**:

  ```
  <%= form_tag(:action => 'add_comment', :remote => true) do |c| %>
      Name:
      <%= text_field :comment, :name %>
      <br/>
      Comment: 
      <br/>
      <%= text_area :comment, :text, :cols => 30, :rows => 10 %>
      <br/><br/>
      <%= submit_tag 'Add comment' %>
  <% end %>
  ```
- action add_comment in **comments_controller.rb**:

  ```
  def add_comment
          @comment = Comment.new(params[:comment])
          @comment.save

          respond_to do |format|
                  format.html { redirect_to comments_path }
                  format.js
          end
  end
  ```
- **routes.rb**:

  ```
  match 'comments/add_comment' => 'comments#add_comment'
  ```

And yet comment is added by refreshing page - add_comment.js.erb is not executed (when renaming both action add_comment and add_comment.js.erb to 'create' works).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<%= form_tag add_comment_path, :remote => true do %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

In your routes:

```
resources :comments do
  post :add, :on => :collection
end
```

Comment: Thanks, works at last. I did try this route, but it seems I do not understand the difference between "add_comment_comments_path" and ":action => 'add_comment' (:controller => 'comments')" in form_tag arguments, and that was a reason of my problems - could You explain?